# Javascript regular expression for textbox which should restrict only 2 digits from (1-99)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a regular expression which should restrict only `2` digits from `1-99` only in the text box.

I have tried below code:

```
function validatenumber(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex =  /^[0-9]{1,99}$/  // allow only numbers [0-9] 
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/](http://jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/)

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: What code? I don't see any

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: @Tushar please check my code

Comment: Use html min and max attributes, instead of regex:

    `<input type="text" min="1" max="99" ... />`

Comment: If you want to check for  a range, try [regex for range utility](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range). `1-99` shortened a bit and anchored would result in `/^[1-9]\d?$/`

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/1/ is close to what you want I think. Still a bit broken (hence not an answer)

Answer (score 1):

**You may use regex as Html5 Pattern**
**update**
 `^[1-9]\d?$` or `^0[1-9]|[1-9]\d$`

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" title="Use number 1-99" pattern="^[1-9]\d?$" required />for 1 or 2 digits
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" title="Use number 1-99" pattern="^0[1-9]|[1-9]\d$" required />for only 2 digits
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/6/)**

Comment: Patterns do not require the `^` and `$`, they're implicit. Also, this will accept `0` which the OP wants to exclude.

Comment: ^0[1-9]|[1-9]\d$  = (^)Line begins with (0) zero, [1-9] followed by "1-9" once, [ | ] a horizontal line that does not belong, [0-9] zero through nine once after the character that does not belong which will likely error, [\d] a single digit , [$] the end of the line.

Comment: Walid Toumi's example below accounts only for 1-99 bound to the start, and end of input.  His is actually the most correct pure regex yet.  But as mentioned your code is mangled in your jsFiddle, so even the right code would likely not work for you even when someone does provide the correct regular expression. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: allow only number between 1-99

```
^[1-9]\d?$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you load your code into the text area in regexr (http://www.regexr.com/) and play around to create your own based on the criteria you're looking to achieve.  This is an excellent resource where you can test regular expressions against your own text.  The correct regular expression would be:

```
   var oldPatternCatchesEachSingleDigits = /\d*/g; 
   var patt = /(\d{1}\d?)*/g;  //catch at least one, OR two digits ( IF exists) at least once, but as many times as they exist.
   // Any amount of digits in the global string(form value in your case)
   var str = "The best answers are on StackOverFlow!22";
   //this should count all of the single digit instances in the entire "str" variable, you'll make the "str" variable equal to your form's string.
   var res = patt.(str); 
   // This will return the 2 digits.
   function(res) {
   //function consumes the res object form your form pattern, against your string(form string)
   if (res.length > 2) {
   //If you have more than 2 digits, return(exit) with the alert function to tell them to update the form.
   return function() { alert("Sorry, too many digits") };
   } else {
   //continue with your code as intended here
   };
```

Here's a link to exactly how to execute it using plain javascript, which should work fine within your form. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp)

Comment: Thanks fro the input b

Comment: The part where I state "This will return the 2 digits" what I mean literally is that pattern will return ALL of the digits entered into the form.  The if/else statement will count those instances of digits and allow 1, or 2 of them.  That keeps > 2 out of the process, and allows you the opportunity to execute any additional code you want to.  Similarly you could use the pattern "\d{1,2}" which would mean 1 or 2 instances of a digit.

Comment: Ahhh, looking @ your re-comment about using zero through to the literal ninety-nine (you should probably write your digits in text when explaining your catch condition for regular expressions btw)... *See edited code snippet answer above.

Comment: I would try code below.  I was working on your JSFiddle for 20 minutes just to get your syntax right, your case corrected, and your code cleaned up and comprehensible. Sorry man my eyes are burning for bed @ this point or I'd finish for you... but I got you moving in the right direction here: http://jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/5/ Also, you really need to acknowledge camelCasing, and you shouldn't have any functions occur "onBlur" rather use onKeyUp event when the form's length value is > 1.

Comment: @torazaburo My answer was just more verbose, and hopefully understandable as "(\d{1}\d?) * " where I explain that bracketed "1" means "1" digit, "question" mark means "questionably" there or not, that being "surrounded" in parenthesis makes it 1 "surrounded" regex capture, and that the star "symbol" "symbolizes" each "surrounded" group as many times as needed.  All this really is a moot point as the 0-99 should be a dropdown form with 0-99 options instead to prevent this issue.

Answer (score -1):

By looking at [your code](https://jsfiddle.net/38oocx2o/) you made a small mistake. Your regex should look like this:

```
var regex =  /^[0-9]{1,2}$/  // allow only numbers [0-9]
```

Your quantifier was wrong which allowed a number with 99 digits.

Comment: Its no working btw i need the inputs from 1-99 not from 0

Comment: The reason this isn't working, is because it's looking for the numbers to be at the beginning of the line ("^") digit, digit once or twice ("[0-9]{1,2}") followed immediately by the end of a line ("$").  This would only work where 2 digits are the ONLY text in the form.  You can try it without the caret and dollar sign and this would work as well.